# What happens to an incoming connection trying to connect to a socket already processing a request?

Tags: c, sockets, server

I can accept() incoming connections while I listen() on my socket, but once I have accept()ed a connection and am processing the request, what happens to an incoming connection request trying to connect on the port that my busy socket is bound to?

Is this handled by the operating system with a timeout or is the attempted connection simply dropped?

If a context is needed, assume BSD sockets on linux.

Answer (score 4):

From the [accept(2) manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html):

> ```
>    The accept() system call is used with connection-based socket types
>    (SOCK_STREAM, SOCK_SEQPACKET).  It extracts the first connection
>    request on the queue of pending connections for the listening socket,
>    sockfd, creates a new connected socket, and returns a new file
>    descriptor referring to that socket.  The newly created socket is not
>    in the listening state.  The original socket sockfd is unaffected by
>    this call.
> ```

So other connections are building up in a queue on the original socket, waiting for your application to respond to them by calling `accept()` on it again. (Bugs aside, there's no such thing as other connections that want to be bound to the state of the newly accepted socket since unlike a LISTENING socket, it is bound to the specific source address and port of the client that was accepted off the queue.)

Consequently, you should design your application to get back to calling accept on the original LISTEN socket in a reasonable amount of time. Some people use threading, some people fork to have another process for handling each new socket, some people prevent large tasks either on any one socket in their protocol or at any iteration in a main loop that examines each ongoing task at each interval and does a set amount of work.

If you do nothing but accept new sockets as old ones are done then a number of clients will sit patiently waiting if they are trivial and will probably give up on their connections if they are less trivial implementations from existing protocols.

Answer (score -2):

accept() blocks incoming calls until it's socket is free.